# How to make component rerender when props change? (StackBlitz link included)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to React and have a mostly OOP experience. I am trying to create a Map component that allows easily changing its config (zoom level, layers...).

Here is the solution I came up with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fmmajh?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2FApp.tsx. Sadly, MapComponent does not rerender when zoomLevel changes.

I am fully aware that this is probably the wrong way to do it, and I am abusing functional programming principles.

But all "conventional" solutions would require coworkers using my Map component to set up states and functions around it to be able to update the zoom.

I would like to be as easy as calling a function, like I tried doing it (Map.setZoom(1)), even if the syntax is a bit different

Is that possible in React?

Comment: You can apply some tricks to make it work, but this is not the way how you should use React. You need state. Also you are not chaning props, zoomLevel is a number and it is not passed by reference. Even if you manage to change its value from mapProps, you are not changing the props of Map component.

Comment: Related: *[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)*. E.g., *"No, providing a link is not sufficient. The information needed to answer the question must be provided in the question itself."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is exactly one way to cause a rerender in React: set state<sup>1</sup>.  So to do what you want, you will need to make a state. This typically looks something like the following:

```
function MapUsage() {
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0.5);
  return (
    <>
      <Map zoomLevel={zoom} />
      <button onClick={() => setZoom(1)}>Zoom</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

> But all "conventional" solutions would require coworkers using my Map component to set up states and functions around it to be able to update the zoom.

There are a few options for how to share this code, without them having to implement their own state. Option 1 is to write a component which implements the state, and they use that. Indeed, `<MapUsage>` might be exactly that component. Ie, your coworkers could just use `<MapUsage>`, and never use `<Map>` directly.

Option 2: if this logic needs to be used in a wide variety of components, and it's complicated enough that you don't want each component to do its own logic, then you could put the logic into a hook:

```
const useMap = () => {
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0.5);
  const zoomMapBy = (offset: number) {
    setZoom(prev => prev + offset);
  }

  const zoomMapTo = (newZoom: number) {
    setZoom(newZoom);
  }

  return {
    element: <Map zoomLevel={zoom} />
    zoom,
    zoomMapBy,
    zoomMapTo
  }
}

// Used like:

function MapUsage() {
  const { element, zoomMapTo } = useMap();
  return (
    <>
      {element}
      <button onClick={() => zoomMapTo(1)}>Zoom</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

<sup>1) OK, technically there's also forceUpdate in class components, but don't use that.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, using a hook seems to be the best way indeed